# jquery autocomplete custom menu item

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am searching jquery autocomplete to search for entities on a server. I would like to be able to create new entities from the search result list by including an item "Create entity" as the  last result, or only result when there is no result found. From the docs it looks like I would use the select event to create a new entity when I select "Create entity from the results list. I am, however, a bit unsure about the right way to add this extra item to the list, including when there are no search results.

I am using JQuery UI 1.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can override source method to return a custom set of responses.  In this case, Create Entity is always appended to the list returned.  Then handle the select event to prompt for the entity.

```
 var availableTags = ['car', 'duck', 'house'];
 $('#elementID').autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
          var responses = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term);
          responses.push('Create Entity');
          response( responses );
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
          var choice = ui.item.value;
          if (choice == 'Create Entity') {
              var selection = prompt('New Entity', 'default value');
              availableTags.push(selection);
              console.log(selection);
              this.value = selection;
              return false;
          }
      }
  });
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLBan/)

Comment: I get this error message when I try your solution: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'replace' jquery-ui-1.10.3.js:7166

Comment: The error results from the line var responses = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request);

Comment: @CoderJoe, the problem was with not using `request` instead of `request.term`.  I added some more changes and put up a fiddle.  It should do the trick.